# How to use fork (gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-fork

I'm very new with git and gitlab.
I followed this post https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/forking_workflow.html and successfully created a fork of original repo in each user of a shared group.
But after I clone forked repo to my local, make some changes, commit and push it back to forked repo. All other member's forked repo also up-to-date with my commit.
I expected that each forked repo is private before it merged to original repo.
Can someone explain it?

Comment: That sounds pretty broken :/

Comment: Maybe you forked to a group-repository, but not a user-repository? If you do that every user of the group will obviously see all changes to that repository.

Comment: Your expectation should be correct and it's unlikely that a bug like this would go unnoticed except for you. Thus I'd suspect you didn't do exactly what you though (and described here) you were doing. To say more, we would have to see at least the online repositories.

Comment: In the fork section, only group that I created to test is available to choose, not single user and no "add user" option. I know it's not a bug but don't know how to deal with. It just a test repo, nothing special to share. My test is just simple: have some gitlab's accounts, create a original repo in 1 account, create group and add all accounts, fork that repo to created group, login other account, clone forked-repo to local, make changes, commit and push, after that, all forked-repos in shared team also update with latest commit